# ionic2 - retriving data from server and not the response

Tags: php, angular, ionic2

Im working on a mobile app in Ionic2 and angular2 but im having difficulty retriving the proper data from the server. I made a simple php script on my website which should return/echo '1' when data is posted to the server however i retrieve the entire response instead. Below is what my home controller looks like currently.

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
    providers: [LocationMgr, HttpService]
})

export class HomePage {
    dataRecv: any;

    constructor(private http: Http) 
    {
        let data = JSON.stringify({username: 'user'});
        http.post('http://dsykes.esy.es/php/adb.php', data).map(res => res).subscribe(data => { console.log(data.data); this.dataRecv = data; });
    }
}
```

Also, here is the php script I have aswell.

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

    echo 1;
?>
```

The only reason why Im using a POST response is because i plan of advancing my script and server requesting using POST for personal reasons. A GET Request would work fine but I need POST to return the return the data only.

I'm currently runniong on the 2.0.0-beta.32 version of ionic aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh!!! Forgot to include the .json() function at the end of the response map! LOL